# Proxying a HTTP Rest API secured by Kerberos

Tags: rest, kerberos

I have a Rest API service which is Kerberized.
When I query it from my browser, it is okay as Windows automagically manage Kerberos negotiation.

Now I want to build a React/Node app responsible for doing the HTTP request to my Kerberized Service (React/Node here is not so important, it could be any techno).

My Node backend could have a Kerberos keytab and actually request my Kerberized service. But what I want is to use the Kerberos credentials of my end user. And here I'm a little lost. How can I get the Kerberos token of my end user and give it to the Kerberized service ? Do I need to Kerberize my app too ?

Thanks

Comment: _"Windows automagically manage Kerberos negotiation"_ -- that's SPNEGO. Client sends the request; server returns HTTP 401; client gets a Kerberos *(or NTLM)* ticket, either by using the local Windows credentials or by calling the KDC directly, stuffs the ticket in the **HTTP header**, and sends the request again; server checks ticket validity against KDC, returns whatever was requested, and (usually) returns also a signed cookie to avoid further auth overhead for the rest of the session.

Comment: So the magic word is "SPNEGO" -- use that for googling...

Comment: Thank you @SamsonScharfrichter. It is clearer now. So I think I have to find a SPNEGO lib for my backend server (the client of the Kerberized service).